# Get consensus from a MSA fasta file with IUPAC ambiguities in Python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, text-processing, biopython

I have an almost similar question to the topic : https://www.biostars.org/p/154993/

I have a fasta file with align sequence and I want to generate a consensus by using IUPAC code.

So far I wrote :

```
import sys
from Bio import AlignIO
from Bio.Align import AlignInfo

alignment = AlignIO.read("input.fasta", 'fasta')
summary_align = AlignInfo.SummaryInfo(alignment)
summary_align.dumb_consensus(0.3)
```

The "0.3" is the threshold of allele frequency to be considered in the consensus. It means that for each column, if a base is represented at least in 30% of the aligment, it will be taken into account; and if more than one base fit this criteria, the corresponding IUPAC ambiguity code is used.

But the "dumb_consensus" only generate the highest represented base and de facto don't use the IUPAC code.

So do you have a way to do such a consensus using Biopython ( or Python in general ) ?

Thanks

Comment: Did I properly understand that if we have at n site 15% G, 15% C, 35% A, & 35% T, we should put W, if we have 31% G, 29% C, & others equal 20%, we should put G?

Comment: You understand correctly !

Comment: @Vovin So do you have an idea how to code such a problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw solving. Although, Biopython code on GitHub looks not better. You can extend this for your aims.

```
import sys
from typing import Optional
from Bio import AlignIO
from Bio.Align import AlignInfo
from Bio.Seq import Seq
import Bio

def getWitConsensus(alignment: Optional[Bio.Align.MultipleSeqAlignment], threshold=0.25) -> Bio.Seq.Seq:
    alphabet = {"A" : "A",
                "C" : "C",
                "G" : "G",
                "T" : "T",
                "AG" : "R",
                "CT" : "Y",
                "CG" : "S",
                "AT" : "W",
                "GT" : "K",
                "AC" : "M",
                "CGT" : "B",
                "AGT" : "D",
                "ACT" : "H",
                "ACG" : "V",
                "ACGT" : "N"}
    
    threshold *= len(alignment)
    consensus = list()
    
    for i in range(alignment.get_alignment_length()):
        frequences = {"A" : 0, "C" : 0, "T" : 0, "G" : 0}
        for record in alignment:
            frequences[record[i]] += 1
        print(frequences)
        consensus.append(alphabet["".join(sorted(key for key, value in frequences.items() if value >= threshold))])
    return Seq("".join(consensus))

alignment = AlignIO.read(r"input.fas", 'fasta')
getWitConsensus(alignment)
```